# How to give it's place to a new model of the [mater-life-thought] Totality?

Tags: metaphysics

I have a model of the  [mater-life-thought] Totality I build for an IA thesis long time ago and I'm wondering how I can have it to find it's place among others known metaphysical systems ? That could mean where to have it discussed or published; where are the best open places ?

There is a difficulty I'm afraid of that will make reviewers blind to the objective power of what is said in this model : it is a true metaphysical one, meaning it only involve multi-categorical  (mater/life/thought) concepts, concepts that apply the same way to the three categories, that unify them and reveal the underlying structure and logic.  I believe most if not all philosophical thinking come from the nature-mind / nature-human / sensible-intelligible etc. dualism, still close to the original religions anthropomorphic modeling. That's lead mechanically to idealism/epistemology/language ie human focused concepts (or by reaction to materialism) and make multi-categorical modeling disruptif to the point of being unreadable. For ex. I'm pretty sure the reviewers will be not even agree or understand the self-evidence of the metaphysical mater/life/thought partition of beingness and will stay stuck in an epistemological dual stuffitude counter-argumentation. That's bad.

oh and there is another one : it's written in 'art brut', pseudo-amateurish style, has zero jargon or academic pseudo-abstractions and has zero bibliography because being 100% "speculative" and disruptive it doesn't need any; I will not change that but I already stripped the polemic stuff it originally had but also keep some humour and there is a photo of a grinder tool inside !??

And it's in French ! But I'm OK to translate it in this convoluted barbaric atrociously ill-pronounced french creole called english, if somebody cannot read French clear coded thoughts.

LOL I see things are really bad writing this ! But it works and it's the only metaphysical system that really works. I know that because I've done some research at the beginning of my thesis and couldn't find any philosophical modeling of how Reality self-construct in mater-life-thought categories of beings. I even found nobody thinking that way except somewhat a guy named Stephane Lupasco. That why I had to do it myself.

OK this is what this system can do. Please try to think of another system that could do only one of the major achievements listed here :

1. from a unique topological concept, give a both intuitive, deep, precise definition of what is a material thing like a pebble, a living thing like a swift, a thinking thing like 2+2=4
2. give the topological logic that make mater produce life and life thought.
3. from this logic, show by deduction than 2 other unseen categories exists.
4. logically prove that Reality is made of only theses 5 categories
5. shows that the core of reality is recursive infinite self-structuring into code, on five infini-code topologies
6. define precisely what is the being and non-being (non-being exist in this model)
7. has powerful predictions capabilities, for example clearly predict that the micro-macro physical theory physician seek will reveal a quantum objet working from code.
8. give a precise content to vaguely mystic predictions of other authors about the Omega point Theillard de Chardin or the singularity of Kurzweil.
9. something metaphysical special is perceived by some authors about sexuality and mathematics : the model give these intuitions a formal and precise definition.
10. give strong cue for mathematical or algorithmic formalisation of the self-construction of reality in the categories of beings.
11. give the cause why other models doesn't work
12. give a precise and simple criteria to compare the power of models of Totality
13. do all this staying 100% in rational thinking without adding anything to reality : simply give a topological structure and logic of what everybody can see.
14. not in atroce 14000 pages like Hegel but in only 14 pages in clear an concise cartesian French-style, without jargon and pseudo-abstractions
15. human specie being at the interface between two categories (life-thought) this multi-categorical model allow the building of a correctly founded anthropology (not included in the document)
16. from this metaphysical anthropology a politics can be build, disruptive of our judaic-greek realm and habitus.

OK all this sound megalomaniac, I'm sorry for that, next time I'll try to build a humble model of the Totality, I promise :D

So... where to find these true philosophical heroes with both extensive knowledge of classical metaphysical systems and open-minded enough to escape the nature-human epistemological camisole ?

Comment: Write a paper; call it e.g. "The New Metaphysics" and send it to some specialized Journal.

Comment: I agree that it is bad to be "*stuck in an epistemological dual stuffitude counter-argumentation*". Beyond that, I don't know enough to say other than Mauro's suggestion. It sounds like verging on Nonduality, so you could check in with those folks. Maybe The Center for the Study of Nonsymbolic Consciousness.

Comment: you are right, I have to translate it in English and submit it to these chatGPT advised journals : 
* Philosophical Review: https://www.dukeupress.edu/the-philosophical-review
* Mind: https://academic.oup.com/mind 
* Journal of Philosophy: https://www.journalofphilosophy.org/
I don't know the usage : should I submit to all or one by one ? I found more metaphysics oriented ones with google but I don't know the audience. Do you have advises here ?